# How to prove $\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin a}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos a}\right)\ge 3+2\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove the inequality:
$$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sin a}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\cos a}\right)\ge 3+2\sqrt{2}; \text{ for } a\in\left]0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right[$$

Comment: what is $a$ here?

Comment: Simply not true. When $\sin a=\cos a=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, for example.

Comment: is it $(1+\frac{1}{\sin(a)})$ or $\frac{1}{1+\sin(a)}$?

Comment: a should be from 0 to pi

Comment: Probably $[0,\pi]$ isn't true, either, since $\sin a=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\cos a=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is going to give a negative value for the product. You probably want $a\in(0,\pi/2)$. But just guessing.

Comment: you're right ,yeah sorry my mistake.

Comment: @Kristian the left-side surely achieves a local minimum at $a=\pi/4$, and at this value, the left side is equal to the right side. Then show that the derivative of the left-side in the interval $(0,\pi/4)$ is negative and the derivative of the left-side in the interval $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$ is positive. This will suffice to show the inequality.

Comment: The endpoints of the interval don't exist. Is it supposed to not include the cases when $a=0$ and $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: yes it doesn't include them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the AM-GM inequality, $$\dfrac{1}{\cos a}+\dfrac{1}{\sin a} \geq 2 \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\sin a\cos a}}$$

Since $\sin a \cos a = \frac12 \sin(2a) \leq \frac12$, we have $\dfrac{1}{\sin a\cos a}\geq 2$.

Hence $$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sin a}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\cos a}\right) = 1+\dfrac{1}{\cos a}+\dfrac{1}{\sin a}+\dfrac{1}{\sin a\cos a} \\\geq 1+2\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\sin a\cos a}}+\dfrac{1}{\sin a\cos a}\geq 1+2\sqrt{2} + 2 = 3+ 2\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 8):

Here is another proof:

Assume $x^2+y^2=1$ then $(x+y)^2=1+2xy$ and 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)=\frac{xy+x+y+1}{xy}=\frac{(x+y+1)^2}{(x+y)^2-1}=\frac{x+y+1}{x+y-1}$$ 
Now rearranging the inequality becomes $x+y\leq \sqrt{2}$. And it can be seen simply that this is the maximum value of $x+y$ given $x^2+y^2=1$, for example $z=x+y$ is a plane and its intersection with the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$has a maximum at $x=y$.

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, so that both $\sin a$ and $\cos a$ are positive and well defined.

$$\bigg (1+\frac{1}{\sin a} \bigg)\bigg (1+\frac{1}{\cos a} \bigg) = 1+ \frac{1}{\sin a} + \frac{1}{\cos a} + \frac{1}{\sin a\cos a}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sin a} + \frac{1}{\cos a} \geq \frac{4}{\sin a + \cos a} \geq \frac{4}{\sqrt{2(\sin^2 a + \cos^2 a)}} = 2\sqrt 2$$

$$\frac{1}{\sin a\cos a} \geq \frac{2}{\sin^2 a + \cos^2 a} = 2$$

So,
$$\bigg (1+\frac{1}{\sin a} \bigg)\bigg (1+\frac{1}{\cos a} \bigg) = 1+ \frac{1}{\sin a} + \frac{1}{\cos a} + \frac{1}{\sin a\cos a} \geq 3+ 2\sqrt 2$$

Equality occurs when $a = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate to find the minimum of the LHS :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\left(\,\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin\,a}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos\,a}\right)\,\right)=0$$

$$\left(-\frac{1}{\sin^2 a}\right)\cos a\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos a}\right)+\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin a}\right)(-\sin a)\left(-\frac{1}{\cos^2 a}\right)=0$$

$$\left(\sin\,a+1\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\cos^2 a}\right)=\left(\cos\,a+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2 a}\right)$$

$$(1+\sin a)(\sin^2a)=(1+\cos a)(\cos^2a)=(1+\cos a)(1-\sin^2a)$$

$$(1+\sin\,a)(\sin^2a)=(1+\cos\,a)(1+\sin\,a)(1-\sin\,a)$$

$$\sin^2a=1-\cos^2a=(1-\cos\,a)(1+\cos\,a)=(1+\cos\,a)(1-\sin\,a)$$

$$1-\cos\,a=1-\sin\,a$$

$$\cos\,a=\sin\,a$$

This only happens at $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$ in the given range.

And here $\sin\,a=\cos\,a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

So the minimum of the LHS is $(1+\sqrt{2})^2=1+2+2\sqrt{2}=3+2\sqrt{2}$